# Executing Oracle stored procedure using Win32:ODBC

Tags: oracle, perl, odbc

I'm using Perl 5, version 14. The Win32::ODBC is VERSION = '0.034'; and Oracle as database.

I'm able to retrieve information from the database using queries like "emp_id, emp_name from emp" by the following code

```
use Win32::ODBC;

$db= new Win32::ODBC("DSN=datasourcename;UID=username;PWD=passwrd") 
        || die "Error: " . Win32::ODBC::Error();

$db->Sql("SELECT emp_Id, emp_name, salary FROM Sample.Emp");

while($db->FetchRow())
{
@values = $db->Data; 
print @values;
}
$db->Close();
```

Instead of using queries in the Perl program, I like to use stored procedures. I have created a stored proc called `sp_rank`.

```
PROCEDURE sp_rank(p_cursorVar out CursorType) 
is
begin 
    open  p_cursorVar for
    select emp_id, emp_name from emp;

End sp_rank;
```

I would like to know how to use stored proc in the Perl and retrieve the data.

Thanks for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Win32::ODBC you can also use the [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.623/DBI.pm) module. You'll also need The [Oracle DB interface](http://search.cpan.org/~pythian/DBD-Oracle-1.56/lib/DBD/Oracle.pm)

Your script could look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $datasource = "datasourcename";
my $username = "foobar";
my $password = "secret";
# connect to your database with a database handle
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:Oracle:$datasource",$username,$password) or die $DBI::errstr();
# create a statement handle for database interaction
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT emp_Id, emp_name, salary FROM Sample.Emp");
$sth->execute();
# fetch the rows and print them
while($sth->fetchrow_arrayref()){
    @values = @$_; 
    print @values;
}
# never forget to close your statement handle
$sth->finish();

# using your stored procedure
# overwrite your finished statement handle with a new one
$sth = $dbh->prepare("sp_rank()");
$sth->execute();
# fetch all your data into an array hashref structure. the column names in your DB are the keys in the hashref
my $data = $sth->fetchall_arrayref({});
$sth->finish();

$dbh->disconnect();
```

Comment: I want to call the stored procedure using Win32::ODBC, not using DBI

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that WIN32::ODBC isn't the best module for this. I would look at DBI and DBD::Oracle modules.

Check out [DBD::Oracle PL/SQL_Examples](http://search.cpan.org/~pythian/DBD-Oracle-1.56/lib/DBD/Oracle.pm#PL/SQL_Examples) in the DBD::Oracle documentation.

Comment: My supervisor wants me to use Win32::ODBC module.